# Square Display in Java

Tags: java

I have homework about loop, but I'm stucking. The require output should be:

```
***
***
***
```

when you enter 3

My code output is

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

when I enter 3. this is my code:

```
package square_display;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Square_display 

{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter positive number:  ");
    int number =input.nextInt();


    while (number > 15 || number<=0)
    {
        System.out.println("Don't input value greater than 15"
                + " and negative number");
        System.out.print("Enter number again: ");
        number=input.nextInt();

    }
  for(int row=0; row<number;row++)
  {
    for (int colum = 0; colum < number ; colum++)
    {
            System.out.println("X");
    } 

  }
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Your output need to print ``*`` and you are using ``X`` .... Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `println`, it will put each character on a separate line. You need to use `print` in inner loop and blank `println` in outer loop.

```
for(int row=0; row<number;row++)
{
    for (int colum = 0; colum < number ; colum++)
    {
        System.out.print("X");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh the good old days. High school homework ? 
Anyway I found your problem its a small error

The problem is the System.out.println so basically your loop ends with a "\n" or new line. You don't want that. So just do a normal System.out.print

Also now your stars will only align horizontally so you need them to start a new line when they reach the number the user has inputted. So add a println in your first for so your for loop will look something like this

```
for(int row=0; row<number;row++)
  {
    for (int colum = 0; colum < number ; colum++)
    {
            System.out.print("X");
    } 
    System.out.println();
  }
```

if you want to be really fancy you can give more control to the user by asking him to enter a row and column number.

```
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of stars in a row:  ");
    int rowNumber =input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of stars in a column:  ");
    int columnNumber =input.nextInt();

    boolean rowNumberTrue = false;
    boolean columnNumberTrue = false;

    while (!rowNumberTrue && !columnNumberTrue)
    {
        if (rowNumber > 15 || rowNumber<=0 ) {
            System.out.println("Don't input value greater than 15"
                    + " and negative number");
            System.out.print("Enter row number again: ");
            rowNumber = input.nextInt();
        }
        else
            rowNumberTrue = true;

        if (columnNumber > 15 || columnNumber<=0 ) {
            System.out.println("Don't input value greater than 15"
                    + " and negative number");
            System.out.print("Enter column number again: ");
            columnNumber = input.nextInt();
        }
        else
            columnNumberTrue = true;

    }
    for(int row=0; row<rowNumber;row++)
    {
        for (int colum = 0; colum < columnNumber ; colum++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
```

Enjoy, hope programming serves you well in the future.

Answer (score 0):

change your loop like

```
for(int row=0; row<number;row++)
    {
        for (int colum = 0; colum < number ; colum++)
        {
            System.out.print("X");
        } 
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row = 0; row < number; row++) {
    for (int colum = 0; colum < number; colum++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
for (int row = 0; row < num; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < num; col++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```